# Deleting P:DATATABLE row by delete button against each row

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-datatable

I have a table and data in it. I have delete and edit button in the last column against each row of table. I want to delete any row from the table pressing Delete button against it. button I need the userId in the row on backend . how can I get that userId from each row on backend.

```
<h:commandButton id="uDeleteId" value="delete" action="#{saveData.deleteUser()}"/[![enter image description here][1]][1]>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `<p:dataTable var="user"`, then your row button can call `action="#{myBean.deleteUser(user.userId)}`, and your deleteUser method signature would be `deleteUser(int userId)`.